Incorrect printing of accents (Zebra ZD420, ZPL)
I have a problem printing accented and special characters on a Zebra ZD420 printer. When I print labels, the accents and some characters are not displayed correctly. For example, “Code Lot réduit” becomes “Code Lot rï¿½duit.
I use the ZPL language and have already tried several solutions:
I've added the ^CI28 command for the international character set.
I've added ^FH before each text field (^FD) containing special characters.
I saved my ZPL file in UTF-8.
I tried to encode the text in UTF-8 in my C# code before sending it to the printer using this code:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ImprimerEtiquetteModifiee()
{
    try
    {
        // Chemin vers le fichier ZPL d'origine
        string cheminFichierZPL = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "etiquette_lot_reduit.prn");

        // Vérifier si le fichier existe
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(cheminFichierZPL))
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Fichier ZPL introuvable." });
        }

        // Lire le contenu du fichier ZPL
        string contenuZPL = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(cheminFichierZPL, Encoding.UTF8);
        contenuZPL = ConvertirCaracteresSpeciaux(contenuZPL);

        // Remplacer les placeholders (@01, @02, etc.) par des valeurs simulées
        contenuZPL = contenuZPL
            .Replace("@01", "CodeLotReduit123")
            .Replace("@02", "Num OC 456")
            .Replace("@03", "Quantite 789")
            .Replace("@04", "CodePF001")
            .Replace("@05", "ProduitFiniXYZ")
            .Replace("@06", "Lot987654");

        // Créer un nouveau fichier ZPL avec le contenu modifié
        string fichierModifie = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "etiquette_modifiee.zpl");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fichierModifie, contenuZPL, Encoding.UTF8);

        // Chemin UNC de l'imprimante
        string cheminImprimante = @"\\FRLORBRIPRTA20P\FRLORBRIPRT8002";

        // Envoyer le fichier ZPL modifié à l'imprimante via le chemin UNC
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(cheminImprimante, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] zplData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contenuZPL);
            fileStream.Write(zplData, 0, zplData.Length);
        }

        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Étiquette imprimée avec succès via l'imprimante : " + cheminImprimante });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Erreur lors de l'impression : {ex.Message}");
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "Erreur lors de l'impression : " + ex.Message });
    }
}



public string ConvertirCaracteresSpeciaux(string texte)
{
    var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "é", "_82" },
        { "è", "_8A" },
        { "ê", "_90" },
        { "ë", "_91" },
        { "à", "_85" },
        { "â", "_83" },
        { "ä", "_84" },
        { "ç", "_87" },
        { "î", "_8C" },
        { "ï", "_8D" },
        { "ô", "_93" },
        { "ö", "_94" },
        { "ù", "_97" },
        { "û", "_99" },
        { "ü", "_9A" },
        { "°", "_F8" }
    };

    foreach (var replacement in replacements)
    {
        texte = texte.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
    }

    return texte;
}

but without success.
Do you have any solutions to this problem? Thank you in advance.
